# How to fix 'Type Error: Cannot Read Property 'name' of undefined when trying to access properties of an object' in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After updating the state of the component with the promise from a 
    fetch call, I am unable to access the properties of the object. 
    When I console.log the object I see it but when I try to access 
    the property it throws a Type error: Cannot read property 'name' 
    of undefined.
    
    `I have tried console.log(Object.keys(filteredStudents[0])) and i 
    get: 
    TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

    class App extends React.Component {
      constructor(prop){
        super(prop)
        this.state = {
          searchField: '',
          students: [],
          menu: 'home'
        }
      }

````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
  componentDidMount() {

 fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
 .then(response => {
        return response.json()
    }).then(data => {
        // console.log(data);
        this.setState({students: data})
    }).catch(err => console.log('error', err))
  }

  render (){
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
    const filteredStudents = this.state.students
    console.log(filteredStudents[0])
    console.log(Object.keys(filteredStudents[0]))
 ````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
      );
    }

    }
  }

I expect the output to return the value of any key I try to 
 access. e.g 
console.log(filteredStudents[0].name) -----> 'leanne'
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the items in the fiteredStudents array before the promise has had a chance to resolve and before your state has been updated. If you wrap your logic inside of a conditional, i.e.

```
if(filteredStudents.length) {
    console.log(filteredStudents[0])
    console.log(Object.keys(filteredStudents[0]))
}
```

Then it should work.